# what do square brackets within a css style do?

Tags: css

I'm editing a site I inherited and I see a css syntax I don't recognize.

Has anyone ever seen this syntax before? 
What do the square brackets within a style mean?

Thanks, Rob

```
.trigger-txt-left {
 color: #0455A3;
 font-family: 'OpenSans';
 float: left;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bolder;
 width: 235px;

[font-family: 'OpenSans';
 font-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Bold';]
[font-weight: bolder;
 font-weight: normal;]
}
```

Comment: I'm just going to sit here and automatically downvote anybody who comes along and says "attribute selector".

Comment: Attribute selector :3

Comment: Definitely attribute selector.

Comment: @Zenith: You are the worst kind of person.

Comment: This is more like a non conventional comment : code between brackets is ignored.

Comment: What is the site written in? Is this passed into some CSS preprocessor?

Comment: @dys - that makes sense as both font-family and weight are also defined outside of the square brackets..

Comment: The validator says it's invalid CSS:  http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/.  In any other language, it could possibly pass as a list.

Comment: Yes it is invalid, and some of those lines would be ignored but not all of them. It's like a broken comment.

Comment: [This W3 page](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html), in the lexical syntax rules under the "Below is the core syntax for CSS" part, seems to indicate (under the `any` token with `'['` and `']'`) that `[ ]` are allowed, or am I reading those syntax rules incorrectly?

Comment: Isn't is specified by including `any` as a potential value for the `value` token just above?

Comment: It's probably an error, but also could be a hack to target IE7.

Comment: @ajp15243: Oh sorry I misread that. In this case, though, the square brackets are appearing outside the declaration and not within the value, but nowhere in the `ruleset` production does it allow `any` around `declaration`.

Comment: @BoltClock Ah, true, so `'['` and `']'` can appear in `value`, but not in/around `declaration`. Didn't read that closely enough, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 8):

The short answer is, nothing. They aren't valid CSS.

Speculating though, perhaps the person was using some code to choose the right one somewhere else, for instance, some PHP might be reading this, then parsing out the `[` and `]` and then selecting the correct property.

Alternatively they might not have realised to use the `/* */` style comments, or perhaps they thought they were being clever by ensuring it wasn't valid in that way.

More likely though it's a mistake, possibly copy and pasted from somewhere.

Comment: This looks like a comment.

Comment: what about input[type=text] which is valid css? Pseudo yes, but still.

Comment: That's not in the declaration block, but the selector. It's called an attribute selector.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR - It is not valid CSS**

It might be helpful to look at the CSS spec in this case. [4.1.8 Declarations and properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#declaration) states that "A property name is an identifier." and the [section on identifiers syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier) explains that:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

... which does not include the `[` character (see the [Unicode character table](http://unicode-table.com/en/)), therefore the identifier (in this case the name of a CSS property within a block) `[font-family: 'OpenSans';\nfont-family: 'HelveticaNeue-Bold';]` is not valid.

Comment: @dystroy: Because that's how a CSS parser would try to parse it? A declaration in a ruleset should always begin with a property identifier, whitespace notwithstanding. That said however, the identifier certainly wouldn't span the entire set of declarations surrounded by square brackets...

Comment: @BoltClock Then the relevant link would probably be more this one : http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets

Comment: @dystroy I didn't include the bit in section 4.1.8 where the spec says that "property names" are identifiers. Sorry about that.